# Excel pivot table formatting keeps changing

Tags: excel, pivot-table

### Suppose I have a pivot table:

[image: Before]

### Now if I add a column in it turns into this:

[image: After]

Clearly the formatting has messed up on the lighter blue cells at the top. I wish these to be the same dark blue as the original.

Even worse it does this when even just the values of the raw data behind the pivot changes, let alone adding columns etc.

Is there a fix for this to lock the formatting as I am having to update many such pivots and changing the colour each time I make a single change on the raw data or want to add a new column on every pivot is getting tedious.

I have looked online and looked into preserve cell width + formatting option bt messing with those has not helped.

Any ideas?

PS: Can anyone embed the images for me?

Comment: In future, try smaller screen shots :) I have also had issues with pivots and formatting so I have just stopped formatting them and or stick to pre-designed formats. Hope someone else has a better answer as I will be saving this question!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have added smaller screenshots can you see them properly?

Comment: Voting to move this to superuser.com since it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the formatting, you need to add a new pivot table style. Within a pivot table, choose Design on the ribbon. You'll see swatches of the existing pivot table styles. Choose the down arrow and "New Pivot Table Style."

[This dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ZnJ.jpg) will appear.

From here, you could specify the header, total row, and row styles you'd want. Once applied to a pivot table, new columns won't affect the style.